How to write Verilog code to describe a quantum system
I would like to ask everyone for some verilog code sources that implement quantum systems so I can refer to them

You can't. Verilog is not a generic programming language but rather a hardware description language. This means that, by definition, Verilog is a way to represent classical digital circuits at the register-transfer level (RTL) that will eventually map onto classical hardware.
